# Center button in MailChimp

Tags: css

[image]

Hello,

How can I center a MailChimp button? The button is centered on desktop, but is shifted right on mobile devices, see the picture. I have been trying playing around with some classes and id's but can not solve it really. Not all the CSS code is necessary I guess. Sorry, I know it is messy. (In the HTML I have HIDDEN... the API-key)

Here is the HTML:

```
<!-- Begin Mailchimp Signup Form -->
<div id="mc_embed_signup">
<form id="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" class="validate" action="https://hotmail.us4.list-manage.com/subscribe/post? HIDDEN... " method="post" name="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" novalidate="" target="_blank">
<div id="mc_embed_signup_scroll">
<span class="text1">Ta del av vårt nyhetsbrev!</span>
<input id="mce-EMAIL" class="email" name="EMAIL" required="" type="email" value="" placeholder="Skriv din e-post här!" />
<!-- real people should not fill this in and expect good things - do not remove this or risk form bot signups-->
<div style="position: absolute; left: -5000px;" aria-hidden="true"><input tabindex="-1" name=" HIDDEN... 
    " type="text" value="" /></div>
<div class="clear">
   <center><input id="mc-embedded-subscribe" class="button2" name="subscribe" type="submit" 
   value="Prenumerera" />
   </center>
</div>
</div>
</form></div>
<!--End mc_embed_signup-->
```

Here are some CSS:

```
.button2 {
   display: inline-block;
   text-align: center;
  font-family: lora !important;
/*    vertical-align: bottom;*/
 /*  padding-bottom: 0px !important;*/
 margin:auto !important;
   height:34px !important;
 line-height :34px !important;
   padding: 5px 12px !important; 
   border: 1px solid #aeb11b;
   border-radius: 8px;
   background: #f8fd27!important;
   background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#f8fd27), to(#aeb11b))!important;
   background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #f8fd27, #aeb11b)!important;
   background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #f8fd27, #aeb11b)!important;
   -webkit-box-shadow: #8d1bb3 0px 0px 24px 0px!important;
   -moz-box-shadow: #8d1bb3 0px 0px 24px 0px!important;
   box-shadow: #8d1bb3 0px 0px 24px 0px!important;
   text-shadow: #ffff33 1px 1px 1px!important;
   font: normal normal bold 20px arial!important;
   color: #111111!important;
   text-decoration: none!important;
}

.button2:hover,
.button2:focus {
   border: 1px solid #f8fd27!important;[![enter image description here][1]][1]
   background: #ffff2f!important;
   background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#ffff2f), to(#d1d420))!important;
   background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ffff2f, #d1d420)!important;
   background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #ffff2f, #d1d420)!important;
   color: #111111!important;
}
.button2:active {
   background: #aeb11b!important;
   background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#aeb11b), to(#aeb11b))!important;
   background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #aeb11b, #aeb11b)!important;
   background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #aeb11b, #aeb11b)!important;
}
.button2:after{
   content:  "\0000a0"!important;
   display: inline-block!important;
   height: 24px!important;
   width: 24px!important;
   line-height: 24px!important;
   margin: 0 -4px -6px 4px!important;
   position: relative!important;
   top: 0px!important;
   left: 0px!important;
   background: url("data:image/png;base64,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") no-repeat left center transparent!important;
   background-size: 100% 100%!important;
}


#mc-embedded-subscribe {
font-family:lato !important;
text-transform: none !important;
}

.validate {
text-transform: none !important;
font-family: helvetica; 
font-weight:700 !important;
width: 100% !important;
text-align: center !important;
font-size: 19px !important;
line-height: 30px;
font-style: normal;
}

#mc-embedded-subscribe-form,
#mc_embed_signup {
padding: 0px 0px !important;
margin: 0px 0px !important;
}

.mc_embed_signup_scroll,
.mc-embedded-subscribe
.validate
.clear { 
position: absolute;
padding: 0px 0px !important;
margin: 0px 0px !important;
left: 50%;
font-family: arial !important;
top: 10%;}

#mc_embed_signup  input.email {
 height:35px !important;
 width: 220px;
}
```

Comment: It seems to work just fine [codepen](https://codepen.io/Vepth/pen/zYvgVZL?editors=1100)

Comment: Nah, there is something going on...maybe it is how the blocks are displayed. You can look at  https://www.botasocialfobi.se/hjalp/        but look from a mobil device or just simply narrow down the screen resoultion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Your code snippet provided is working just fine.**

Problem is that in [your page](http://botasocialfobi.se/hjalp), that you provided in comment, there is `float: right` declared on your button which I saw by inspecting that element:

```
input[type=submit], button, input[type=button] {
  border: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin: 10px 0px 0px;
  padding: 11px 20px;
  float: right;
  ...
}
```

Removing it fixed the issue.

One more thing. Try not to use `<center>` tag as it is **[not supported by HTML5](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_center.asp)**

Since you are using WordPress theme that is maybe not editable, add internal or inline style `float: none` to your HTML page:

### Internal style:

```
<head>
  <style>
    input[type=submit], button, input[type=button] {
     float: none;
    }
  </style>
</head>
```

### Inline style

```
<input id="mc-embedded-subscribe" class="button2" name="subscribe" type="submit" 
value="Prenumerera" style="float: none"/>
```

To inspect an element:

1. Go to your website page
2. Right click on button
3. Left click on "Inspect element"

You will see HTML of your page and next to that CSS. Scroll down to see the code that I provided in my answer.

Comment: Where can I access that code that you wrote and the "float: right;"? I guess they are the original settings for MailChimp. But where could you see it? I am using a WordPress theme.

Comment: Oh, I inspected the element in the browser.

Comment: @Mr_G I have updated my question, maybe this helps better.

Comment: I am kinda new to this. Could you more precisly say how you saw it and where I can change it? It would really help me and also learn me something new.

Comment: Yes it works! Thanks very much, really appreciate it!

Comment: Glad that I helped, feel free to check my reply as an answer by clicking "check" button next to my answer.